# request via the Internet (web) in power query

Tags: python, excel, powerbi, powerquery

There is a website https://exchange.gov.tm/quotations
If you go to this site through a browser, you can see a large table that is located in the  tag
But when I connect to it in power query via the web, this table does not come out.
Can you help with the connection, maybe you can connect to it through python script?[image]

Comment: PowerQuery has problems importing a table that has a lazy load that updates while you are scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Developer Tools" in most browsers, and switch to the "Network" tab. Then refresh the page. You'll see all the requests made. One of them is:

```
https://exchange.gov.tm/api/exports?per_page=100&page=1&group=1209&locale=ru
```

Which returns the table as JSON. Use this URL to load in to PowerQuery.

Example:

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://exchange.gov.tm/api/exports" & "?per_page=1000&page=1&group=1209&locale=ru", [Headers=[Accept="application/json"]]))
```

The following will expand to table:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://exchange.gov.tm/api/exports" & "?per_page=1000&page=1&group=1209&locale=ru", [Headers=[Accept="application/json"]])),
    exports = Source[exports],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(exports, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "group_id", "category_id", "type", "title", "country", "unit", "amount", "point", "place", "currency", "payment", "send", "seller", "price", "is_line", "locale", "created_at", "updated_at", "total", "category"}, {"id", "group_id", "category_id", "type", "title", "country", "unit", "amount", "point", "place", "currency", "payment", "send", "seller", "price", "is_line", "locale", "created_at", "updated_at", "total", "category"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Comment: i have got 2 row
1. "meta_text"
2. "exports" which contains list of records,
but where is my table?

Comment: Click on `List` in the `exports` row. Right-click on List column header and select `To Table`. Then click on the double arrows ↰↱ in the column header and untick at the bottom `Use original column name as prefix`. There is your table. Or use the additional PowerQuery added to the answer above.